# Android app with ads and release for few user

Tags: android

I developed and android app that has AdMob Banner Ads. Initially I want to release only for few user. If I add beta user , would I earn money from adds and how many beta user I can have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the closed testing track allows unlimited testers only if you add testers through Google Groups or Google+ Communities. E-mails are restricted to a total of 200 lists and 50 lists per “track” (read: test), with each list limited to 2000 testers.

And you can earn in closed testing as well, but it is recommended to use testing ads when you are testing instead of proper ads.

Here is an article which explains in detail regarding beta setup.
https://instabug.com/blog/google-play-beta-testing-setting-effective-tests/